# swift EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error in playground

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I have the following test code...

```
import Foundation

var n = 5

let binSlots = 64
var numOfOnes = 0
var inSequence = false

func toThePower(number: Int, power: Int) -> Int {
    var ans = number
    for _ in 1..<power  {
        ans = ans * number
    }
    return ans
}

// the following line is fine
if n <= toThePower(number: 2, power: 4) {
    print("ok")
}

for i in stride(from: binSlots, through: 0, by: -1) {
    // the following line produces this error:
    // // error: Execution was interrupted, reason: 
    // EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
    let pCalc = toThePower(number: 2, power: i) 

    if n >= pCalc {
        n = n - pCalc
        numOfOnes += 1
        inSequence = true
    }
    else {
        if inSequence {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Any clues as to what's causing the error? I know that if I comment out the following...

```
//    for _ in 1..<power  {
//        ans = ans * number
//    }
```

the error goes away however I don't know why or why the first call to the function runs with no errors.

I have looked at other similar posts but none was similar to my case.

your help is appreciated.

thank you.

Comment: Edit your question and discuss what you found when you single-stepped through the code with the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is from this line in your `toThePower` function:

```
for _ in 1..<power  {
```

The problem is that the right side of the range can't be smaller than the left side of the range.

The line:

```
for i in stride(from: binSlots, through: 0, by: -1) {
```

results in you calling your `toThePower` function with a power down to and including 0.

0 is less than 1, hence the crash.

Change:

```
for i in stride(from: binSlots, through: 0, by: -1) {
```

to:

```
for i in stride(from: binSlots, through: 1, by: -1) {
```

to avoid the crash.

Comment: With all the smartness of swift, stuff like this makes me miss 'C'. Thank you @maddy

Comment: hmmm, for a sec I thought that did the trick but it didn't. Even checking for the value of `power` and return 1 if it is 0 did not resolve the issue. I have also changed the `toThePower()` function loop to use `stride(:: )` with no luck :(

Comment: OK. the problem was that calculating 2^63 or 2^64 was freaking it out. I changed the code to use `UInt` since all the results were `<= UInt.max` but with no luck. Using `Double` fixed the issue but the code was ugly due to casting back and forth which is why I did not use `pow()` in the first place! Anyhow, I lowered my upper limit from 64 to 32 and all is good :)